# In ASP.NET MVC 2, how do I get Html.TextBoxFor to render a textarea instead of an input tag?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

This code:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DonationMessage) %>
```

Renders an `input type=text` tag, but I want a `textarea`. I tried this in my entity but it didn't make a difference:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string DonationMessage { get; set; }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DonationMessage) %>
```

Comment: Good heavens I feel dumb. Thank you. This is an example where learning purely by examples can fail you. I didn't see this in an example, and googling just didn't cut it. Had I read more documentation initially, I'd have known. I'm going to go read a book on this. BBL :)

Comment: Try something like this in Google "asp.net mvc html textarea". I'm just learning MVC as well, so I have to be resourceful. I did buy an MVC book on Kindle and it's been a big help as well.

Comment: I was googling "textboxfor textarea"... making the wrong assumption was not helping me :)

Answer (score 4):

if u want your DataType attribute to be at work you can use EdiotrFor method instead

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.DonationMessage) %>
```

this will take into account your DataType attribute plus there are dozen other things that you can do with Editor Templates